# ZeroMQ Pub/Sub drops messages only when subscribing to topics

Tags: multithreading, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I'm losing messages only when I'm subscribing to topics.

Here's the scenario:
The subscriber subscribes to a specific topic and then calls the publisher in a different thread (with the same context and the same "subscribed topic").
The publisher receives the "subscribed topic" and publishes it.

When I run two procedures (meaning 2 subscriber threads and 2 publisher threads), I receive only one message on one of the threads (randomly).
I have no idea why I'm losing the second message.

Publisher thread:

```
void *publisher = zmq_socket(ptStruct->zContext, ZMQ_PUB);
assert(0 == zmq_bind(publisher, "inproc://#1"));
printf("Publishes to %d \n", ptStruct->iID);
assert(-1 != zmq_send(publisher, &(ptStruct->iID), sizeof(ptStruct->iID), 0));
zmq_close(publisher);
```

Subscriber thread:

```
void *subscriber = zmq_socket(ptStruct->zContext, ZMQ_SUB);
assert(0 == zmq_connect(subscriber, "inproc://#1"));
assert(0 == zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, &(ptStruct->iID), sizeof(ptStruct->iID)));
printf("Subscribed to %d \n", ptStruct->iID);

/* Now run the publisher in a different thread */
OSTHREAD_CreateThread(&ptThread, publishThread, ptStruct, NULL);

assert(-1 != zmq_recv(subscriber, acRec, 255, 0));
printf("Got %d \n", acRec[0]);
zmq_close(subscriber);
```

I run the subscriber thread twice and this is the output:

```
Subscribed to 1
Subscribed to 2
Publishes to 1
Got 1
Publishes to 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two different publishers that are `bind()`-ing to the same `inproc` endpoint "#1" - an endpoint can only be bound to once, the second publisher is failing to `bind()` on the same endpoint and then not sending the message.

Additionally, you'll probably want to add in some delay between the publisher `bind()`-ing and then `send()`-ing the first message, due to the [slow joiner](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out) problem - the publisher could attempt to send, and then drop, your message before the publisher and subscriber finish connecting, which would also cause you to lose your message.

Comment: Interesting.. Although it worked when I didn't use any filters in the subscription. Do you think that there's a better way to do this than pub/sub? (because I need something like pub/sub but many to many)

Comment: You don't give enough detail to really understand what the best way to design your communication. You can do many to many with pub/sub, you just need to bind each pub to its own endpoint and then connect each subscriber to each pub. But why do you need more than one pub socket? Without understanding what you're trying to do I can't suggest what might be best in your case.